# Compositor: dilate/erode except on predefined edges?

Tags: compositing-nodes, edges

[image: Example]

A cube with 2 materials and their respective passes. Each ID mask is dilated and then subtracted from the original mask to create the black outline. Notice the only input is from the material pass.
How do I remove the black line between the two materials?

[image: Image without compositor.]

Here is my character, see how each finger has a different material.

[image: After compositing, I have the colors and outlines I want.]

After compositing, I have the colors and outlines I want.

How do I remove the black line between the two materials?
The goal is to get an outline around fingers but not where the finger is attached to the hand.... And I need to keep the material outlines separate for when the fingers clench into a fist, or cross boundaries in any way.

Comment: Have you tried [freestyle](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/freestyle/introduction.html)? I think it would be better suited to your needs.

Comment: Freestyle is too unpredictable, I've tried it a few times and the lines flicker around curves or where two objects meet.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

So this is as close as I could get. It's not ideal but I could go in frame by frame and remove the excess outline created from the hand you see on top of the lowered fingers (middle and ring).

I'll try to break down the process. If someone can find a way to fully remove those lines I'd love it:

Step 1: Duplicate mesh to a second layer, remove fingers from the first layer.

[image: Main node tree]

Step 2: Remove the back-faces from the hand and fingers with a mix of your material and transparency.

[image: Back-faces removed]

Step 3: In compositing, instead of using the "dilate/erode" node to create your outline, use "filter->filter->lapace" node.

[image: Hair]

Step 4: Specifically for the fingers, you'll take the difference between the outline generated from the hand on the first layer, and the outline generated from the fingers on the second layer (you cannot have fingers on the first layer and you must have the whole body on the second layer).

[image: Difference]

Coming out of the top outputs of "fingers.R" and "hand.R" in the image above are just the outline created from the lapace node, the skin *color* is added at the end of this tree with the "alpha over" node.

I hope I'm making sense.
Again, freestyle just doesn't work for me because of it's inconsistencies; I'd prefer to have complete control over where my outlines are generated. There have been some instances of freestyle where I lose parts of the outline around the main body, and that just won't work.